# Reach a number with different integers (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

This is the question:  Consider a currency system in which there are notes of seven denominations, namely, Rs 1, Rs 2, Rs. 5, Rs. 10, Rs. 50, Rs. 100. If a sum of Rs. N is entered through the keyboard, write a program to compute the smallest number of notes that will combine to give Rs. N.

Here is my code. The program seems to be stuck in infinite loop

```
public class ReachNwithCurrencyNotes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n,temp = 0, a = 1, b = 2, c = 5, d = 10, e = 50, f = 100, sum = 0, countA = 0, countB = 0, countC = 0, countD = 0, countE = 0, countF = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter N");

        n = input.nextInt();

        temp = n;

        do {

            if (temp-f>=100) {
                sum = sum + f;
                countF++;
                temp = temp - f;
            }
            else if (temp-e>=50) {
                sum = sum + e;
                countE++;
                temp = temp - e;
            }
            else if (temp-d>=10) {
                sum = sum + d;
                countD++;
                temp = temp - d;
            }
            else if (temp-c>=5){
                sum = sum + c;
                countC++;
                temp = temp - c;
            }
            else if (temp-b>=2){
                sum = sum + b;
                countB++;
                temp = temp - b;
            }
            else if (temp-a>=1){
                sum = sum + a;
                countA++;
                temp = temp - a;
            }
        } while (sum<n);
        System.out.println("N completed with\n" + countA + "\n" + countB + "\n" + countC + "\n" + countD + "\n" + countE + "\n" + countF);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `%` is an option, then I would use it instead.

Answer (score 2):

All of your conditions check if paying `a, b, ...` will leave a strictly positive (`>= 1`) quantity. So you will never pay the last needed bill whatever it is, and your sum will never reach `n`, thus the infinite loop.

For example, if you can get to `0` by paying a `5`, you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the number was 1, then temp-a is equal to 0, so nothing will happen and the program will loop forever.

All the conditions such as (temp-b>=2) look wrong, try replacing them with something like:

```
(temp-b>=0)
```

or simply

```
(temp>=b)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on my comment, here an example:

You start with the highest value you have and go down to the lowest.

```
 //input: integer value 'in'
 int rest = in % 100;
 int n100 = in / 100;
 int n50 = rest / 50;
 rest %= 50;
 int n10 = rest / 10;
 rest %= 10;
 int n2 = rest / 2;
 rest %= 2;
 int n1 = rest % 2;
```

If you input 273:

```
   1: rest = 273 % 100 = 73
   2: n100 = 273 / 100 = 2
   3: n50 = 73 / 50 = 1
   4: rest = 73 % 50 = 23
   5: n10 = 23 / 10 = 2
   6: rest = 23 % 10 = 3
   7: n2 = 3 / 2 = 1
   8: rest = 3 % 2 = 1
   9: n1 = 1
```